# C2143 error c++

Tags: c++, string

Sorry for this question but I am stuck.
I have folowing syntax:

```
class xx
{
..some simple fields like: int t;  // )))
public: class  anotherClass;
xx();
MyObj* obj();
string*  name(); //error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'   

}
```

i have write `# include <string>`
What does compiler wants from me?!

Comment: BTW it's normally spelt 'curiosity' without the 'u'. (I always get that one wrong myself :-/)

Comment: @Rup: you're wrong; **[that's not what he is called, his name is called 'curiousity'](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/60song.html)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It wants you to tell him *which* string. You want the standard one:

```
class xx
{
  public:
    std::string*  name();
};
```

Now, I'm not sure why you would be returning a *pointer* to a string. That's a segmentation fault waiting to happen, if you ask me. Two more viable options that seem reasonable to me:

```
class xx
{
    std::string _name;
  public:
    const std::string& name() const 
    { 
        return _name; // WARNING: only valid as long as 
                      // this instance of xx is valid
    }
};
```

or

```
class xx
{
  public:
    std::string name() const { return "hello world"; }
};
```

Comment: @OscarKorz: true. It is common idiom in the sample that I gave (returning a reference with the same lifetime as the class instance itself). Of course, lifetimes matter, but so do unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 3):

You need to either fully qualify string or bring it into the current namespace:

```
std::string* name();
```

or

```
using std::string;
```

In a header, it's generally considered bad practice to pollute the global namespace, so the first is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not know what string is because string is residing in the namespace std, not in the global namespace. You need to change string to std::string.

In your cpp file you can use "using namespace std;" or "using std::string;" and then just write "string". But you should never use using-namespace-declarations in header files.

BTW, as the others say returning a string* is unusal, normally you would return a string.